# Wordpress plugins overload compiled assets

Tags: php, css, wordpress, webpack

I use webpack to compile my assets, so i have only 2 of them: `main.js` and `main.css`.

But if I install any plugin that requires `bootstrap.css` (for example) it looks that there is no enqueued bootstrap and enqueue it.

So, now I have 2 (different versions) of bootstrap and my site is broken.

How can I deal with this problem?